# Play Spotify song on Spotify client in background using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, spotify

I remember a while ago, I clicked pressed play on a song on a website, and without any fuss, it would start playing on my client that was open my computer. It wouldn't even open, just start playing.

The behaviour that I want for my website is, when the user clicks a button, music will start to play if Spotify is open.

Things I've looked at, that do not work:

- Using the Spotify Web API
- Embedding the Spotify player
- Opening the song URL

The problem is, that I don't want the song to play from the website, i.e. I don't want the website to become a Spotify Connect client.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do what you need with the Spotify Web API.

Just look for all available devices [like this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/get-a-users-available-devices/).

And then start playback on one of those devices like [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/start-a-users-playback/), specifying the `device_id`.